# Peer is not finding which is connected to other network. Multipeer connectivity Framework

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am using MultiPeer Framework and I am not able to discover peer which is advertising itself. And other peer is connected to other Wifi Network.
I mean if both device are connected on same network it works fine. If I move a device to other network it does not work.
Can you please explain where I am doing wrong or whats the best solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Multipeer Framework, it is required that the devices are connected over the same wi-fi network. Otherwise, you would have to use bluetooth.

Comment: can you please tell me any other solution through which my iOS devices can communicate peer to peer. you can tell me any solution like open source or should I need to go to implement peer to peer from scratch?